# Is there a way to run an interactive shell command during a git(-flow) hook?

Tags: git, hook, git-flow

I want to write a git hook for git flow, that starts an interactive rebase when finishing a feature branch and automatically squashes commits.

Currently what I have like looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Runs before git flow feature finish
#
# Positional arguments:
# $1    The friendly name of the branch
# $2    The origin remote
# $3    The full branch name (including the feature prefix)
#
# The following variables are available as they are exported by git-flow:
#
# MASTER_BRANCH - The branch defined as Master
# DEVELOP_BRANCH - The branch defined as Develop
#
NAME=$1
ORIGIN=$2
BRANCH=$3

# Implement your script here.
`git rebase -i $DEVELOP_BRANCH`
# To terminate the git-flow action, return a non-zero exit code.
exit 0
```

However, this wont open the rebase window, but instead will stop anything from happening.

Answer (score 0):

I did type it wrong:

```
git rebase -i "$DEVELOP_BRANCH"
```

This worked.